# Properly delegating requests to an inner object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to find out whether or not I'm looking at containment/delegation the correct way.  In this example I've got a `Car` and a `Radio` type.  I have a function that takes in a string and changes the value of the `IsOn` property of the Radio object.  I would like to know which approach (or neither) if a sufficient way to solve this problem.

(please ignore the validation of the incoming string into the TurnOn method, for simplicity's sake)

```
 public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        protected Radio radio = new Radio();
        public Radio MyRadio
        {
            get { return radio; }
            set { radio = value; }
        }

        public class Radio
        {
            public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
            public bool IsOn { get; set; }
            public void TurnOn(string turnOn)
            {
                if (turnOn == "yes")
                {
                    if (IsOn)
                        Console.WriteLine("The radio is already on");
                    else
                    {
                        IsOn = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("You turned on the radio");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsOn)
                    {
                        IsOn = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("You turned off the radio");
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

I tested this in my Main method, the output is beside each lines in the comments

```
  Car c = new Car();
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyRadio.IsOn); //false
    c.MyRadio.TurnOn("yes"); //you turned on the radio
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyRadio.IsOn);//true
    c.MyRadio.TurnOn("yes"); //the radio is already on
    c.MyRadio.TurnOn("no"); //you turned off the radio
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyRadio.IsOn); //false
```

The other way I thought of doing this was added the following function to the Car class

```
public void CarChangesState(string s)
        {
            MyRadio.TurnOn(s);
        }
```

I tested it with the following code and everything worked as expected

```
Car c2 = new Car();
            Console.WriteLine(c2.MyRadio.IsOn);//false
            c2.CarChangesState("yes"); //you turned on the radio
            Console.WriteLine(c2.MyRadio.IsOn);//true 
            c2.CarChangesState("yes");//the radio is already on
            c2.CarChangesState("no");//you turned off the radio
            Console.WriteLine(c2.MyRadio.IsOn); //false
```

Is one example better than the other?  From my reading of `Pro C# and the .NET Framework` I have a feeling like the first iteration isn't really delegation, but I'd like to know if one method has fewer disadvantages than the other.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Why do you pass a string into the ChangeState method? A more readable option is `bool`. The best option would probably be an `Enum RadioState`. Passing a magic string really feels like the "stringly typed" anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is delegation. This first approach is not.

Delegation means that you ask some object (e.g. `Car`) to turn on the radio. `Car` doesn't know how to turn on a radio, but he knows who does. So he passes the message along to `Radio`.

Your first approach, to simply expose the radio object, is not delegation, because the `Car` never receives the request to turn on the radio, and thus never delegates the request to turn on the radio.

In addition, many purists would criticize your first approach because it violated the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), but in practice, I find myself doing that occasionally for the sake of expedience/readability. (Maybe I'm just a crappy dev, though?)

Comment: the first way seems more declarative i.e. easier to read and understand, but perhaps I need better naming conventions.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie For what it's worth, I find it personally acceptable to have a `Car.Radio` field in many cases. It's one of those fuzzy things where your intuition and design experience will give you a feel for which is better. It would be nice to have a formulaic set of guidelines, but sometimes I find it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: That's one of the bigger problems when you're first learning.  Everyone has their own flavor and it can be hard to tease about the facts to determine that they mean the same thing.  I just always try to think in terms of extensibility and best practice and also not violate YAGNI (you aint gonna need it) by making solving problems that only enterprise applications face.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Yes.. beware of "veterans" and "experts" who strongly push the one-true-way of design or claim their approach is "obviously better" without presenting strong evidence.  I will say that violating the Law of Demeter can lead to writing some very cumbersome unit tests. http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/18/breaking-the-law-of-demeter-is-like-looking-for-a-needle-in-the-haystack/

Answer (score 0):

You maybe refering to something like this:

```
    class Car
    {
        // Car 'has-a' Radio.
        protected Radio radio = new Radio();
        public Radio MyRadio
        {
            get { return radio; }
            set { radio = value; }
        }
        public void TurnOnRadio(bool onOff)
        {
            // Delegate call to inner object.
            MyRadio.TurnOn(onOff);
        }
    }

    public class Radio
    {
        public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsOn { get; set; }

        public void TurnOn(bool turnOn)
        {
            if (turnOn)
            {
                if (IsOn)
                    Console.WriteLine("The radio is already on");
                else
                {
                    IsOn = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("You turned on the radio");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (IsOn)
                {
                    IsOn = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("You turned off the radio");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Since Radion is-a car? not , then car has-a radio you call directly to turn the radio on or off.

```
Car c = new Car();
c.TurnOnRadio(true);
```